# fetch from db and display feedparser feed

Tags: django

Just started learning and doing the homework and i am entirely new to code. I can't able to configure `for loop` correctly here, can you find out ..?

i just want to display some news and feeds into my homepage. I create one model class name `Feedinfo` and the `URLField` name is `url_name`. Using feedparser i wrote this view funtion

```
def base_view(request):
    feed_detail = Feedinfo.objects.all()
    for feed in feed_detail:
        settings = feed.url_name
        pprint.pprint(settings)
    feed = feedparser.parse(settings)
    info = []

    for entry in feed.entries:
        info.append(entry)
    return render_to_response('app/landing.html', {'info': info}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but pprint shows

```
u'http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/MKuf?format=xml'
u'http://feeds.feedburner.com/jeyamohan?format=xml'
```

So question why the second feed url only display into homepage.?

Comment: Think about what is the value of `settings` in line six, which is outside the loop.

Comment: `feedparser setting` and second `forloop` should be inside the first `forloop`

Comment: oh .. ! wat u mean by setting..?

Comment: feedparser.parse or i ll give you example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `feed` will have the list of urls then `feed = feedparser.parse(settings)` should be inside the loop, then only every url have the advantage of `feedparser` then followed by the each entry like:

```
for detail in feed_detail:
    settings = detail.url_name
    feed = feedparser.parse(settings)
    for entry in feed.entries:
        info.append(entry)
```